# Книги/видео/сайты по C#

Tags: c#, книги

Чтобы не то чтоб изучить полностью язык, а понять сами основы. Так сказать, механику этого языка.

P.S.
желательно с подробными примерами.

Comment: Такие вопросы уже задавались тыщу раз. И тыщу раз на них давались исчерпывающие ответы. Еще один автор забанен в поиске?

Comment: Какой паразит поставил плюс?

Answer (score 6):

Если не хотите перегружать мозг глубокими подробностями, а желаете изучить только основы, то почитайте Троелсена. Я вот лучше напишу, с помощью чего не нужно изучать программирование (в том числе и c#). Так вот я крайне не рекомендовал бы изучать его по каким-либо видеокурсам (ну если это не какие-нибудь лекции условного Стэнфордского Университета или MIT), потому что этими видеокурсами скорее всего окажется очередное богомерзие наподобие видеокурсов Евгения Попова или какого-нибудь, прости Господи, Артема Кашеварова

Answer (score 4):

Если и вправду хотите разобраться в самых-самых основах, возьмите Джеффри Рихтера "CLR via C#". Там расписано вплоть до ассемблера и кеша процессора.

Comment: человек, желающий понять только основы, голову сломает об Рихтера, после чего плюнет на программирование.

Comment: @DreamChild: смотря как понимать слово "основы". Если иметь в виду "на чём всё основано там внутри", нужен Рихтер. Если основы означают "руководство для новичка", Троелсен подойдёт. Если "основы" означает "попроще, чтобы не напрягать мозг" -- вон из профессии!

Comment: Хм..ну основы - это априори начальный уровень. А связь между основами и "тем, на чем все основано" в данном случае примерно такая же, как между каналом и канализацией. Иными словами,  им вряд ли автор имел в виду низкоуровневую составляющую .NET и особенности работы CLR. Судя по вопросу его интересуют именно начальные знания о языке (скорее всего даже без особого углубления в CLR)

Comment: @DreamChild: красивая игра слов, но она здесь не по делу. Например, [основами математики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) называется вовсе не сокращение дробей и задачи про лжецов и рыцарей. В любом случае, Рихтер или Троелсен -- выбирать автору вопроса, а вот с отношением "не перегружать мозг" я коренным образом не согласен.

Comment: @VladD?, ну что вы, разве я где-то порекомендовал "не перегружать мозг"? А по поводу того, что имел в виду автор, давайте не будем спорить - так или иначе ему порекомендовали и то, что он имел в виду на ваш взгляд, и то, что  - на мой.

Comment: @DreamChild: согласен! "Пусть расцветут тысячи цветов" (ц). Вам +1 от меня.

Answer (score 1):

Вот неплохой сайт для изучения [Professorweb](http://professorweb.ru/)

Answer (score 1):

> Чтобы не то чтоб изучить полностью
> язык, а понять сами основы. Так
> сказать, механику этого языка.
>
> P.S. желательно с подробными
> примерами.

[Примеры](http://www.csharp-station.com/)

Единственное, он на английском. Но думаю, Вам не понадобиться много знаний английского языка, там все просто и наглядно, описывает все нужные базовые функции в сокращенном виде. Я думаю, если Вы захотите разобраться с остальными вещими и узнать о всех "плюшках" языка и технологии .NET - обращайтесь, поможем, чем сможем.

Answer (score 0):

Поддерживаю рекомендации выше. Если хотите основы и логику языка - читайте Шилдта, Троелсона, Рихтера.
Можете также посмотреть видео - [C# для начинающих](http://itvdn.com/ru/video/csharp-starter), [Основы программирования на C#](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/2247/18/info).